# show Jframe but not show title bar on task bar

Tags: java, swing

In my application, I show a Jframe at the corner of screen for notification.
And I want to show only Jframe and do not display a title bar at task bar.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 32):

If you want the window to just appear and have neither a title bar nor appear in the taskbar, use a `JWindow`.

If you want the window to appear and have a title bar but to not appear in the taskbar, use a `JDialog`.

Comment: This is correct. JFrame is meant to be the primary application window (ie, a framed window). JWindow is any popup window. JDialog is framed, but its a secondary window, so it doesn't show up in the taskbar.

Comment: 1) I use method to hide title bar in JFrame is frame.setUndecorated(true)...it work fine. but I want to work with it onClick of button or any other click over frame.

2) With JWindow there is no prob with Title Bar...but then how we can move window from one position to another.

pls suggest if do u have any idea.

Comment: Imagine applications like skype, dropbox, uTorrent. They hide the framed window and also hide the taskbar icon. This operation is *minimizing to tray* and it's perfectly valid to do it with jFrame too.

Answer (score 14):

JDK 1.7 brings you method setType. Use following method.

```
JFrame.setType(javax.swing.JFrame.Type.UTILITY)
```

Comment: `java.awt.Window#setType(java.awt.Frame.Type.UTILITY)`

Comment: Doesn't Work in Linux. Works in Windows. Don't Know about Mac.

Answer (score 6):

"All you'd have to do is to set your JFrame "type" property to "UTILITY" and there you have it!"

This does work, at least under Java 1.7, its the same as the above "myframe".setType(Type.UTILITY) instead of Type.POPUP. Testing type popup (under win 7) does not work to remove it from the taskbar, Type.UTILITY does.

Undecorated will not have the desired results (as that removes the title bar from the window, not the taskbar)

```
public class Window extends Container implements Accessible {
    /**
     * Enumeration of available <i>window types</i>.
     *
     * A window type defines the generic visual appearance and behavior of a
     * top-level window. For example, the type may affect the kind of
     * decorations of a decorated {@code Frame} or {@code Dialog} instance.
     * <p>
     * Some platforms may not fully support a certain window type. Depending on
     * the level of support, some properties of the window type may be
     * disobeyed.
     *
     * @see   #getType
     * @see   #setType
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public static enum Type {
        /**
         * Represents a <i>normal</i> window.
         *
         * This is the default type for objects of the {@code Window} class or
         * its descendants. Use this type for regular top-level windows.
         */
        NORMAL,

        /**
         * Represents a <i>utility</i> window.
         *
         * A utility window is usually a small window such as a toolbar or a
         * palette. The native system may render the window with smaller
         * title-bar if the window is either a {@code Frame} or a {@code
         * Dialog} object, and if it has its decorations enabled.
         */
        UTILITY,

        /**
         * Represents a <i>popup</i> window.
         *
         * A popup window is a temporary window such as a drop-down menu or a
         * tooltip. On some platforms, windows of that type may be forcibly
         * made undecorated even if they are instances of the {@code Frame} or
         * {@code Dialog} class, and have decorations enabled.
         */
        POPUP
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a JWindow instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a JWindow...

```
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Notification extends JWindow {
   private final int WIDTH = 200;
   private final int HEIGHT = 30;

   public Notification() {
      positionWindow();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   // Place the window in the bottom right corner of the screen
   private void positionWindow() {
      Toolkit aToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension screen = aToolkit.getScreenSize();
      int xPosition = screen.width - (WIDTH + 10); // Right edge of the screen
      int yPosition = screen.height - (HEIGHT + 10); // Bottom edge of the screen
      setBounds(xPosition, yPosition, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you'd have to do is to set your JFrame "type" property to "UTILITY" and there you have it!

Comment: not descriptive at all, and from my research there is not such thing, even under the inherited Window.setType() there is no UTILITY type.

Comment: You are wrong, @SammyGuergachi. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setType%28java.awt.Window.Type%29  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfectly for me. 

   // Remove icon from Windows task bar.
   setType(Type.UTILITY);

Answer (score 3):

Use this, but it work only on JDK 1.7 or openJDK 1.7 :

```
// only on JDK 1.7 or openJDK 1.7

 JFrame f = new JFame(" frame not displayable in the task bar ");
    ...
    ...
    f.setType(Type.POPUP); // No Place on task bar, but stays on top of all others system applications frame
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javaapplication4;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author ravi
 */
public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    Main()
    {
       setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Main m=new Main();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a call to `setUndecorated(true);`. It tells the window manager to not add the title bar and window buttons.

Note: this must be called while the frame is not displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately, undecorated `JFrame` windows still appear in the taskbar, at least on the system that I'm testing on right now (Windows 7).

Comment: Ah, missed that on the first read. Then you want to look at using a non-modal `JDialog`. It will behave the same, but will not have the minimize/maximize buttons on the titlebar as minimize without a taskbar presence makes no sense. Now, if you're trying to do a notification popup where it has no titlebar, no border, and no taskbar presence, you may want to look at JWindow.

Answer (score 0):

One answer mentions to use `JWindow` which works out of the box for Windows and 2 others suggest to use `javax.swing.JFrame.Type.UTILITY` which is not needed in Windows if you already use `JWindow`. If you find yourself using `JWindow` under **Linux** and you still see it in the taskbar, you can use `POPUP` instead:

```
sWindow.setType( Window.Type.POPUP );
```

Read the documentation though, this might do other things as well (like removing decorations) which you *might* not need.