# Question about JFrames

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe

I am running Windows. When you run an application on Windows, you get a button task bar where you can click it to maximize and minimize it. Is it possible to create a JFrame without this or some other component that has the functionality of a JFrame but without adding it to the task bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show Jframe but not show title bar on task bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054347/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a JDialog instead of a JFrame. On a JDialog, you can set the 'modal' property, which means no 'upper bar' or anything is displayed.

Do make sure the JDialog has no parent frame or anything though: a modal JDialog will block the GUI of any parent GUI component. But if you just use it as your main component there is no problem :)

Comment: or a [`JWindow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html).

Comment: +1, @Vincent Koeman and @Bala R, for actually understanding the question and providing correct solutions -- cool beans. :)

Comment: The window cant be modal. But it seems as if JWindow was what I was looking for.