# java - system tray background image on linux is not transparent

Tags: java, linux, swing, awt, system-tray

I am developing a Java application with system tray. I am using SystemTray class avaiable on Java and png image for the icon. The image has transparent background and works fine on Windows and Mac, but the image is displayed with white background on linux.

Someone knows what's the problem and how can I fix it?

I searched a lot for it, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: should depend on your desktop environment, what are you using and which version? I'm having a lot of transparent icons with XFCE on fedora18 and I'm guessing most modern DEs will support such.

Comment: I am using gnome and ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem under Debian Jessie and Xfce 4.10 -- any news on this?

Comment: The TrayIcon has several problems on several OSs.  Here's an outline of them, including the gray-background. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35919788/3196753