# How to set buttons inside taskbar IconImage in java

Tags: java, imageicon

I want to know if it is possible to set `buttons` on taskbar `ImageIcon` in a java program? I saw this work on MPCH player.

[image: while hover on IconImage, these button is appears]

i placed my icon with like this:

```
mainframe.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icon.jpg")));
```

how can i add controls on this part? thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? When I google for "java taskbar button", I immediately find [HOW TO: Make a System Tray Icon in Java in 3 Steps](https://kebomix.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/how-to-make-a-system-tray-icon-in-java-in-3-steps/). Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open popup(Menu) on task tray icon with left click using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428042/open-popupmenu-on-task-tray-icon-with-left-click-using-java)

Comment: emm...actually, no, this example that you pointed to is about "menu item in **system tray**",  i tried this code but the result is menu item on system tray icon, i want to create buttons on **taskbar** icon like the image above.