# Hide JFrame in windows toolbar

Tags: java, swing

is it possible to hide a JFrame window in the windows toolbar? If yes, how? Was searching everywhere for nearly one and a half hour and couldnt find anything which would be helpful...

EDIT: I dont want to hide the icon in the taskbar but i want to hide the window and therefore create an icon in the toolbar, right next to the clock, audio etc...

EDIT2: I want to hide the window in the system tray. Was searching for that word in english^^

PROBLEM SOLVED: The Class i was looking for was the [tray icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) class.

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly, but an option could be to use a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`. Especially if the frame you want to hide from the toolbar is a popup from another frame in your java application. All popups should be dialogs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show Jframe but not show title bar on task bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054347/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar)

Comment: Are you after a [tray icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)?  Given that you said 'right next to the clock, audio etc...' this might be what you want.

Comment: Yes i meant the tray icon. Tried to translate manually from german to english^^

Answer (score 1):

Use `JFrame.setType(Type.UTILITY)`:

```
public class X extends JFrame{
    X(){
        super("No taskbar");
        setType(Type.UTILITY);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new X();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JFrame.setType(javax.swing.JFrame.Type.UTILITY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`. Because, `JDialog` does not appear at windows toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on ur main class:

```
//
...
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/imgs/app_ico.png");
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image img = kit.createImage(url);
```