# Minimize a resizable JDialog

Tags: swing, java-8, jdialog

I'm working on an swing application with a main window (which extends `JFrame`) from which several child windows can be opened (more than 1 contemporarily).
These windows are all non-modal and resizable.
So far, I implemented these 'child' windows as a `JFrame`. However, I get a new icon on my Windows taskbar for each opened Window.
I therefore tried to implement these windows as a `JDialog` with type `ModalityType.MODELESS`.
Looks OK except that a JDialog has no minimize button.

Is there a way to resolve this?
I.e., I need to create non-modal and resizable child windows that can be minimized.
`JInternalFrame` is not an option since the main frame is not just a container with a `JDesktopPane` and child windows should be able to cross the borders of the main window.

For those interested:
Child windows register and unregister themselves on the main window when being opened/closed.
The main window has a menu with a 'Windows' item and child windows are added/removed from that menu upon registration/unregistration.
The user can switch between the various windows by selecting an item within this menu.

Comment: Where would it go when minimized? Or, why not just use the close button?

Comment: When minimized it should simply be hidden. When reactivated (by selecting the corresponding menu item in the main window), the original contents should be shown. The child windows may be quite big and may cover the main window completely. That's why I need them to be minimizable.

Comment: Okay, I get that you need them minimized, but your minimizing sounds the same as closing them. So why not just use the close button?

Comment: When closing a child window, its contents (that may have been edited by the user) is lost. I don't want that. And I don't want to force the user to save or start all over again just because he wants to take a look within another window.

Comment: Just don't lose the contents of the window when it is closed? When they click close, hide the window, that is all. Also, you might want to check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054347/show-jframe-but-not-show-title-bar-on-task-bar

Comment: When the user explicitly closes a window, I want it to be 'clean' when it's opened again. Furthermore, I don't want to keep possibly 100 windows in memory. I'll have a look at the link you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718054/to-add-minimize-maximize-button-to-jdialog-orjpanel) help?

Comment: @yur: I checked that link before asking the question. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am offering two suggestions.

- A. Don't use the close button to get rid of the contents.
- B. Set the type of child jframes to be utility.

I think having the JDialog close button destroy data is setting your users up for data loss. I would instead use the close to just hide the window, and then have controls inside of the dialog to cancel/finish/restart.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class DiFrame{
    static JDialog log;
    static JFrame ame;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Father of two");
        
        JButton one  = new JButton("dialog");
        
        one.addActionListener( evt->{
            if(log==null){
                log = new JDialog(frame, "dialog child", false);
                log.add(new JTextArea("fresh start"));
                log.pack();
                log.setVisible(true);
            } else{
                log.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        JButton two = new JButton("frame");
        
        two.addActionListener( evt->{
            if(ame==null){
                ame = new JFrame("frame child");
                ame.add( new JTextArea("fresh start") );
                ame.setType(Window.Type.UTILITY);
                ame.pack();
                ame.setVisible(true);
            } else{
                ame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.add(one, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(two, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

  
}
```

Click the dialog button and it shows the dialog. Then the text area can be modified. When the dialog is closed it can be re-opened.

Click the frame button and a jframe is shown. ( I actually cannot check if this shows up as a new application because it doesn't on my computer anyways. )

Comment: Setting a frame to 'utility' causes it to have a smaller title bar. Not an option. Implementing them as JDialog and setVisible(false) on the windowClosing event. Separate 'close' button that disposes the window. Not a real solution but the best workaround I guess. Thanks.